# WP MVC: Pagination in index controller not working

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm using the WP MVC plugin to create a plugin which provides a database of names as part of my Wordpress website.

The below controller retrieves the right information from 2 database tables, but suddenly pagination is not working anymore. Do I need to use paginate() instead of find()? If yes, how would a similar query look using paginate()? Unfortunately there are no examples available.

Thanks!

names_controller.php

```
<?php
class NamesController extends MvcPublicController {

    public function index() {
            $objects = $this->Name->find(array(
                    'joins' => array('Origin'),
                    'selects' => array('Origin.id', 'Origin.origin', 'Name.id', 'Name.name', 'Name.gender', 'Name.meaning', 'Name.origin_id'),
                    'page' => 1,
                    'per_page' => 20,
                    'conditions' => array(
                            'Name.name LIKE' => 'A%'
                    )
            ));

            $this->set('objects', $objects);
    }
}
?>
```

=================== UPDATE ======================

I replaced the find() with paginate() unfortunately the join doesn't work anymore. Furthermore it IGNORES e.g. page, per_page etc parameters.

Anyone an idea?

```
            $params = $this->params;
            $params['page'] = empty($this->params['page']) ? 1 : $this->params['page'];
            $params['per_page'] = 20;
            $params['joins'] = array('Origin');
            $params['selects'] = array('Origin.id', 'Origin.origin', 'Name.id', 'Name.name', 'Name.gender', 'Name.meaning', 'Name.origin_id');
            $collection = $this->Name->paginate($this->params);
            $this->set('objects', $collection['objects']);
            $this->set_pagination($collection);
```

Comment: does this help you get to a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095067/wp-mvc-how-to-perform-a-join-using-the-paginate-method

Comment: I looked at this post before unfortunately I did not find it very helpful, but I updated my post with what I tried so far.